# Undo/redo in a graphics application

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to provide an undo/redo facility in my application.

As an example, consider this series of invocations:

```
gr.Drawrectangle(pen, p1, p2);
gr.FillEllipse(brush, p1, dx, dy);
```

I'd like to store the invocations in a list of some kind and be able to undo them. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: What is your goal? (Ie. What problem are you trying to solve)

Comment: Why you want to combine these in a list?

Comment: I'm trying to make an MS Paint like program. I want to delete the last value in the list when a user presses 'undo' for example.

Comment: how do people think this is a incomplete question? I can understand it fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand completely that what you want but can create a list of actions or functions.

```
List<Action<Graphics>> actions = new List<Action<Graphics>>();

actions.Add(gr => gr.Drawrectangle(pen, p1, p2));
actions.Add(gr => gr.FillEllipse(brush, p, x, y));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection to get list of methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx

But for 'undo' button I think, you should use some kind of cache, to keep previous bitmaps. Lets say last 10 moves (bitmaps) can be put in memory and next moves in temporary files.